# google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am doing the tutorial on https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html

and working on the Python API section, I launched
    `python classify_image.py`

Here I am getting the error message out like so:

`A protocol message was rejected because it was too big (more than 67108864 bytes).  To increase the limit (or to disable these warnings), see CodedInputStream::SetTotalBytesLimit() in google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h.`

So, I tried to access the file coded_stream.h, but I cannot get to it as the directory tree is getting me to google/protobuf and no further. There is no io directory.
Any hints on what I should do now?

thanks
Peter

Comment: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.coded_stream#CodedInputStream.Limit.details

Answer (score 6):

You need to install the custom protobuf pip package as detailed here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#protobuf-library-related-issues

**EDIT :** (updating link) https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/install/install_linux#protobuf_pip_package_31

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solves my problem. I first tried the tutorial with a docker image which ran perfectly OK, then wanted to do the identical thing on a native install of Tensorflow on my iMac and there it failed.

Comment: On my anaconda environment based installation of tensorflow, I do have a problem with the protobuf pip package as proposed above. I get a message    

     Successfully installed protobuf-3.0.0b2.post2

Hence I suppose the install went very well. But now making a simple test of entering into Python and importing tensorflow, I get this error

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/peterhirt/anaconda/envs/tf1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.10.dylib

  Reason: image not found

any hint what is not working 

Thanks a lot
Peter

Comment: Could you file an issue on github tensorflow and link it here? Having it working in Anaconda seems useful

Comment: submitted an issue at [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1755)

Comment: Missing Link 

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#protobuf-library-related-issues

Comment: both links are not working, need help! Getting the same error